# How can I use drill-embed with file extensions different from the default ones?

Tags: apache-drill

I'm trying to test apache drill via drill-embed but all my json files are jsonline files with the jl.gz file extension.

If I rename them to json.gz it works but this is undesirable in my case.

How can I tell drill that jl.gz files are actually json?

PS: I tried adding a `bootstrap-storage-plugins.json` to $CP but drill-embed doesn't seem to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do not use bootstrapping. That is only for distributed environments and using the [Web Console](http://drill.apache.org/docs/plugin-configuration-basics/#using-the-drill-web-console) or REST API [is recommended](http://drill.apache.org/docs/plugin-configuration-basics/#bootstrapping-a-storage-plugin). It probably goes without saying that the gz file must be zipped, not an unzipped JSON file with a gz extension. Create a new storage plugin configuration, for example myplugin, based on the default dfs storage plugin.

1. Start the Drill shell and go to `http://<IP address or host name>:8047`. Select Storage in the toolbar. The dfs storage plugin configuration appears in the list of default configurations.
2. On the Storage tab, under Enabled Storage Plugins, click UPDATE to copy the dfs storage plugin configuration.
   The configuration of the plugin appears.
3. Copy the configuration and go back (just cancel the configuration).
4. On the Storage tab, enter a name in New Storage Plugin. For example, enter myplugin. Each configuration registered with Drill must have a distinct name. Names are case-sensitive.
5. Click CREATE.
6. In Configuration, in the formats section, change the json format to specify extensions: "gz"

   "json": {
     "type": "json",
     "extensions": [
       "gz"
     ]
   },
7. Click CREATE.

Now, in the Drill shell, you can query the JSON file named something.gz:

```
use myplugin;
select * from `/Users/me/donuts.gz` limit 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering it @catpaws. I'm still very new to drill. When you talk about the default dfs storage plugin, what file are you specifically talking about?

Comment: Sorry, added some steps to get you to the dfs default storage plugin config. It would probably help to take a look at http://drill.apache.org/docs/json-data-model/ before attempting to query your json file.